# C# - Memory leak when passing an event as parameter to a subclass

Tags: c#, events, memory-leaks, delegates

during the last days I tracked down a memory leak in our application. I know the idea of the developer, who wrote this code, but I am not really about why the leak occurs. The idea was to have a class, which contains an event. The class will instantiate another class, which shall add a event handler to the event in the Init-method and removes it, calling the Stop-method. The problem is, that the event isn't removed from the main class and the InvocationTargetList is growing and growing.
Here is an example source code, which shows the problem:

```
public class SampleEventArgs
{
    public SampleEventArgs(string s) { Text = s; }
    public String Text { get; private set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public delegate void SampleEventHandler(object sender, SampleEventArgs e);

    public event SampleEventHandler SampleEvent;

    public SubClass m_SubClass = new SubClass();

    public MainClass()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            m_SubClass.Init(ref SampleEvent);
            m_SubClass.Close();
        }
        if (SampleEvent != null)
            Console.WriteLine("SampleEvent InvocationTargetList length: {0}", SampleEvent.GetInvocationList().Length);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class SubClass
{
    public event MemoryLeakTest.MainClass.SampleEventHandler m_Subscription;

    public void Init(ref MainClass.SampleEventHandler SampleEvent)
    {
        SampleEvent += NewEvent;
        m_Subscription = SampleEvent;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        m_Subscription -= NewEvent;
    }

    public void NewEvent(object sender, SampleEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Well, I already fixed the problem by passing the class to the Init and Stop method and also implemented the IDisposeable pattern, but I am not 100% sure, why the code above produces the memory leak. Is it caused, because assigning the SampleEvent to m_Suscription will create a copy of the event and so the event will only be removed from the m_Subscription variable in the Stop method? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we already know delegates are immutable and that's why you used `ref` parameter to subscribe event.

Now look this method closely

```
public void Close()
{
    m_Subscription -= NewEvent;
}
```

You actually unsubscribe from a copy, and **not** from original delegate which is in `MainClass`. In other words you're re-assigning the field in sub class only not the field in main class.

Comment: So this means, that the line "m_Subscription = SampleEvent;" creates a copy of the original delegate. That's what I wasn't sure about. Thanks for the explanation!